# how to find which user Deleted records of particular database on azure db instance

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

How can I find which user has deleted or dropped records of particular database on azure db instance.
I want to know the following information:

- IP-Address
- Username

Comment: Can you try this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-auditing

Comment: It can be found only if sql auditing is enabled,, For web apps - app insights should be enable only then we will have all logs. or if you have subscription to raise request in MS, might they can help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable SQL Auditing. The following example enables audit when record(s) are deleted on a table.

```
Set-AzureRmSqlDatabaseAuditing -ResourceGroupName "resourceGroup"
 -ServerName "SQL Server Name" -DatabaseName "AdventureWorksLT"  
 -StorageAccountName "storageAccount" 
-AuditActionGroup "SUCCESSFUL_DATABASE_AUTHENTICATION_GROUP", "FAILED_DATABASE_AUTHENTICATION_GROUP", "BATCH_COMPLETED_GROUP" 
 -AuditAction "DELETE ON database::[AdventureWorksLT] BY [public]"  
 -RetentionInDays 60
```

The BATCH_COMPLETED_GROUP on the audit will provide you the IP address and user name of the login (user) that you need.